# Index.html not loading when npx serve is run (caddy, nodejs)

Tags: node.js, npm, npx, fastify, serve

I'm running fastify on node.js and using Caddy server for reverse proxying localhost to a domain (`authsvc.dev`) that serves up an index.html file in this UI project.

All was running fine until a couple days ago. Now, when I run `npm run ui` I get the following error messages in the console. The index.html file is not being served up. The src/public/index.html file exists and was working a couple days ago, but maybe some issue with `npx serve {{path-to-file}}`? Please help!

```
ERROR: Not able to read /{{path-to-proj}}/ui/src/public/index.html/serve.json: ENOTDIR: not a directory, open '/{{path-to-proj}}/ui/src/public/index.html/serve.json'
npx serve src/public/index.html exited with code 1
```

Not sure where or why index.html/serve.json is trying to be read and how to go about fixing it.

I'm running macOs Big Sur v11.6

Some things I've tried.

1. Deleting node_modules and `npm install`
2. Deleting package-lock.json and `npm install`
3. updating to latest npm
4. Changing to different version of node (now on v14.15.1)
5. Clearing npm cache `rm -rf ~/.npm` `npm clear cache`
6. `npx serve src/public/` -- allows me to see when I'm at `localhost:5000`, but not `authsvc.dev`

I do have Caddy running with a reverse proxy set up.

```
{
  local_certs
}

authsvc.dev {
  reverse_proxy 127.0.0.1:5000
}

api.authsvc.dev {
  reverse_proxy 127.0.0.1:4000
}
```

Host file

```
127.0.0.1 authsvc.dev
127.0.0.1 api.authsvc.dev
```

package.json scripts

```js
  "scripts": {
    "all": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"cd ../ui\" \"npm run ui\"",
    "server": "cd ../api && npm run start",
    "ui": "concurrently \"nodemon src/index.js\" \"npx serve src/public/index.html\"",
    "ui1": "nodemon src/index.js",
    "ui2": "npx serve src/public/",
    "caddy": "caddy run",
    "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "concurrently": "^6.2.2",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.1.4",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "fastify": "^3.22.0",
    "fastify-static": "^4.2.3"
  }
```

[image: results of npm run all]

Answer (score 0):

Serve should not take an .html file but the folder containing your entire website.
You can try this command : `serve src/public/`, without the `npx` prefix and normally it should work

Comment: I’ll give it another try, but I think I tried that too without success, but I’ll give it another go when I get to my computer. Thanks!

Comment: Still not working for me, but I updated some additional details above. Maybe I was missing some details that could be helpful troubleshooting the issue.